# как сделать плавное появление, и исчезновение текста в консоли в python?

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать плавное появление, и исчезновение текста в консоли. Либо сделать так, что бы текст плавно изменял цвет, допустим с черного на белый, и с белого на черный. Это реально?

Comment: В большинстве консолей цвета берутся из палитры. Скажем 16 фиксированных цветов. Плавно изменить цвет или яркость отдельной буквы невозможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлять конечно можно! Для этого мы в **print()** добавляем именованный аргумент **end=""**, чтобы не было переноса строк и **flush=true**, чтобы вывод был сразу. По умолчанию стоит **flush=false**, и вывод текста в консоль происходит только тогда, когда строка полностью собирается. Т.е **flush** действует как буфер.

```
import time


stroke_to_typewrite = "Hello, this is a typewriter effect example"
# Появление
for letter in stroke_to_typewrite:
    print(letter, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Исчезновение
for i in range(len(stroke_to_typewrite) + 1, -1, -1):
    print('\r' + stroke_to_typewrite[:i], end=' ', flush=False)
    time.sleep(0.1)

print('This is what will be displayed after')
```

Спасибо CrazyElf за дополнение! Удалять текст постепенно всё таки можно =)

Comment: В блок else мы вставляем print() потому, что нам нужно сменить строку на следующую после завершения нашего вывода.

Comment: Что ж нельзя то удалять постепенно, можно и удалять, добавьте вот это: `for i in range(len(stroke_to_typewrite)+1, -1, -1): print('\r' + stroke_to_typewrite[:i], end=' ', flush=True); time.sleep(0.2)` Только `print()` свой ниже по коду перенесите.

Comment: понимаю, что вы этот ответ дали уже давно. Но все же спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

реально.

```
import time

txt = 'я текст'
for i in txt:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(i, end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: Запускать свой скрипт пробовали? И как у него с "исчезновением текста в консоле"? Причем ясно написано: "плавное появление И исчезновение текста". Про "сделать так, что бы текст плавно изменял цвет, допустим с черного на белый, и с белого на черный"  даже не говорю.